# Error in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

I am using the folowing codes  to generate my tikz commutative diagram.

```
    \documentclass{book}

    \makeatletter
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}

    \makeatother

    \begin{document}


\begin{tikzcd}
u \arrow {r} & c
\end{tikzcd}


\begin{tikzcd}
u \arrow [r] & c
\end{tikzcd}

    \end{document}
```

But when i am using `{r}` it is not giving error and if I use `[r]` then it is giving the following error. What I have to do to correct. Because in most of the cases options are in `[]` only. How to work with that?

### Error:

> pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tikz/r' and I am going to ignore it.
>   Perhaps you misspelled it. \end{tikzcd}

Comment: I suspect you have an older version of `tikz-cd`

Comment: means how i can update it??? I am using linux mint 13 and texstudio as my texeditor

Comment: I don't know about Linux Mint, but I'd install a full TeX Live independent from the laziness of GNU/Linux distribution maintainers, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: First, I would try to find out what your current version of `tikz-cd` is.  But linux mint 13 seems to be pretty old, so probably egreg is correct.  In any case, if you don't succeed to update it, you can also read the documentation of `tikz-cd` for your version (`texdoc tikz-cd`, or find `tikz-cd-doc.pdf`).

Answer (score 2):

You package is outdated. I guess, both `tikz-cd` and `pgf` so you will have to use the old syntax `\arrow{<direction>}{<label text>}` until you manage to update your distribution. There are several posts on this topic around this homepage here.